# Консольные приложения

Tags: c#, консоль

Вот вопрос, во многих книгах которые я читаю, везде начинают обучение в консольных приложениях... но вот вопрос, почему именно в них, и второй **Зачем воообще консольные приложения??**

Comment: К сожалению, в винде такая консоль, что лучше бы мои глаза ее не видели. Я пока не начал писать под линукс, тоже не понимал ценности консольных приложений. В никсах консоль на порядок удобнее и красивее, и писать под нее намного легче, чем под виндовскую.

Comment: С позиции CLI разницы в консолях (`System.Console`) под различные ОС нет. Не подскажете, в чём же всё-таки состоят различия?

Comment: Во-первых, внешний вид винконсоли вызывает во мне тоску. Линуксовые терминалы (gnome-terminal, konsole и т.д.) на порядок симпатичнее. И шрифт там нормальный, длина строки нефиксированная, и куча других удобств. Про набор команд я не говорю. Вроде бы PowerShell это решил. 
Я не очень знаком с C#, не знаю как там управляется терминал, т.е. как изменить цвет шрифта, фона и т.д. В винде на низком уровне это делается с помощью API функций, в никсах -при помощи управляющих последовательностей, что на порядок проще и приятней. 
В винде вроде в консоли большие проблемы с русской кодировкой.

Answer (score 7):

Есть разные виды приложений и их классификаций. Одна из них: приложения бывают трансформирующие, интерактивные и реактивные (реального времени). Так вот, первые из них, трансформирующие, характеризуются тем, что берут данные на входе (упрощённо -- входной файл), работают какое-то время, обязательно конечное, и выдают результаты (упрощённо -- в выходной файл). Таких задач очень много и участие человека там в процессе минимально. (Частный случай -- это подзадачи какого-то интерактивного приложения). Вот для них и нужны консольные приложения. Ну и плюс интерактивные задачи, где диалог -- не графический, а текстовый. Где-то так. Ну и задачи реального времени редко бывают с графическим интерфейсом. Плюс всякие сервера (http, ftp и т.д.)

Comment: ага понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле, большинство приложений являются именно консольными или вообще не имеют пользовательского интерфейса. Сюда относятся различные серверные приложения, службы, трансформирующие приложения, упомянутые выше и т.д. и т.п.

Дело в том, что консоль - это всего лишь форма пользовательского интерфейса. И реализовать такой интерфейс обычно проще, чем графический. Основная логика программы не зависит от интерфейса, поэтому обучение эффективнее строить на консольных программах. Кроме того, консольные приложения проще тестировать и отлаживать.

Наконец, консольный интерфейс, часто оказывается удобнее и эффективнее графического. Просто современные пользователи не привыкли пользоваться консолью и не знают возможностей современных консолей. Почитайте книгу Джефа Раскина про интерфейсы. Там много про это говорится.

Answer (score 2):

Учатся сначала на консольных приложениях, чтобы сначала понять основные принципы языка, основы синтаксиса и т.д. Основная работа в приложениях вообще идет за GUI, поэтому нужно сначала все это освоить, а построение GUI обычно стоит на тех же основных принципах, что и другие приложения: те же принципы ООП и т.д.

Не везде GUI нужен и не везде он полезен. Например, серверы. Да и в обычных программах он обычно используется для ввода и вывода каких-то данных, а вся обработка идет за кулисами. На серверах GUI будет тормозить работу, создаст лишние проблемы с безопасностью. Да и не нужен он там. И вообще, программ без GUI (скажем так шире) на самом деле много больше, чем с графическим интерфейсом.